# How do I add libraries like from PIL import ImageGrab using pyinstaller hidden-imports

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I can add libraries like import requests to hidden imports, but from PIL import ImageGrab but how do I add such libraries?

I get this error when I do --hidden-import "json.loads" like this Hidden import 'json.loads' not found

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a proper [mcve]. The title implies problems with `PIL` but your question implies problems with `json`.

Comment: my problem was not only about json or PIL, there are dozens of libraries, I got an error, I wrote only 2 of them